# karma unit test running issue Error $injector:modulerr failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm new to angularJS unit testing and I have added a new unit test but I'm running into this issue:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module FeeBuddy due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

this is my `karma.conf.js` file dependecies call :

```
files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      //'node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js',
      'public/js/vendor/materialPreloader.min.js',
      'js/server.config.js',
      'js/main.controller.js',
      'js/controllers/*.js',
      'js/services/*.js',
      'js/directives/*.js',
      'js/factories/*.js',
      'js/components/*.js',
      'js/modules/**/*.js',
      'js/routes.js',
      'js/modules.js',
      'js/module.js',
      'js/filters/*.js',
      'js/modules/**/module.js',
      'js/dependecies.js',
      'test/unit/*.js'
    ],
```

Even if I uncomment the `node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js` still i have the same issue

Comment: You're certain you've installed angular-material using npm?

Comment: yes npm install angular-material --save-dev

Comment: @AmineToraa. Did you solve this? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @SatishKumar i tried by deleting all my node modules and install them again then the problem was salved, it may be an npm module version issue but im not sure ... you can share your code if you want

Comment: @AmineToraa. I got it working. Thanks anyway.